# my category wise pagination of post widget not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I want to create a widget for my theme.
facility of the widget is user can select category wise post and give limitation how much posts show from a category then it show that post and also so pagination so that all of the post with that category can see by using pagination.

here is my code

```
class colornews_featured_post_style_five_widget extends WP_Widget {

   function __construct() {
      $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'widget_featured_posts_style_two colornews_custom_widget', 'description' =>__( 'Display latest posts or posts of specific category.' , 'colornews') );
      $control_ops = array( 'width' => 200, 'height' =>250 );
      parent::__construct( false,$name= __( 'TG: Category wise Posts', 'colornews' ),$widget_ops);
   }

   function form( $instance ) {
      $tg_defaults['title'] = '';
      $tg_defaults['number'] = '';
      $tg_defaults['type'] = 'latest';
      $tg_defaults['category'] = '';
      $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $tg_defaults );
      $title = esc_attr( $instance[ 'title' ] );
      $number = $instance['number'];
      $type = $instance['type'];
      $category = $instance['category'];
      ?>
      <p><?php _e( 'Layout will be as below:', 'colornews' ) ?></p>
      <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/style-2.jpg'?>"></div>
      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'colornews' ); ?></label>
         <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></p>
      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to display:', 'colornews' ); ?></label>
         <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('number'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" /></p>
      <p><input type="radio" <?php checked($type, 'latest') ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'type' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'type' ); ?>" value="latest"/><?php _e( 'Show latest Posts', 'colornews' );?><br />
       <input type="radio" <?php checked($type,'category') ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'type' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'type' ); ?>" value="category"/><?php _e( 'Show posts from a category', 'colornews' );?><br /></p>
      <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'category' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Select category', 'colornews' ); ?>:</label>
         <?php wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'show_option_none' =>' ','name' => $this->get_field_name( 'category' ), 'selected' => $category ) ); ?></p>
      <?php
   }

   function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
      $instance = $old_instance;
      $instance[ 'title' ] = strip_tags( $new_instance[ 'title' ] );
      $instance[ 'number' ] = absint( $new_instance[ 'number' ] );
      $instance[ 'type' ] = $new_instance[ 'type' ];
      $instance[ 'category' ] = $new_instance[ 'category' ];

      return $instance;
   }

   function widget( $args, $instance ) {
      extract( $args );
      extract( $instance );

      global $post;
      $title = isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ? $instance[ 'title' ] : '';
      $type = isset( $instance[ 'type' ] ) ? $instance[ 'type' ] : 'latest' ;
      $category = isset( $instance[ 'category' ] ) ? $instance[ 'category' ] : '';


         $get_featured_posts = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type'             => 'post',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
            'category__in'          => $category
         ) );


      echo $before_widget;
      ?>
      <div class="magazine-block-1">
         <div class="tg-block-wrapper clearfix">
            <?php
               if ( $type != 'latest' ) {
                  $background_color = 'style="background-color:' . colornews_category_color($category) . ';"';
               } else {
                  $background_color = '';
               }
               if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo '<h3 class="widget-title title-block-wrap clearfix"><span class="block-title" ' . $background_color .'><span>'. esc_html( $title ) .'</span></span></h3>'; } ?>
               <div class="featured-post-wrapper clearfix">
                  <div class="tg-column-wrapper">
                  <?php
                  $i=1;
                  while( $get_featured_posts->have_posts() ):$get_featured_posts->the_post();
                     ?>

           <div class="tg-column-1"><div class="first-post" style="margin-bottom:30px">
                        <div class="single-article clearfix">
                           <?php
                           if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                              $image = '';
                              $title_attribute = get_the_title( $post->ID );
                              $image .= '<figure>';
                              $image .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="'.the_title( '', '', false ).'">';
                              $image .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $featured, array( 'title' => esc_attr( $title_attribute ), 'alt' => esc_attr( $title_attribute ) ) ).'</a>';
                                 //$image .= colornews_colored_category_return(0);
                              $image .= '</figure>';
                              echo $image;
                           }
                           ?>
                           <div class="article-content">
                              <h3 class="entry-title">
                                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                              </h3>
                              <?php $no_featured_image_extra_class = has_post_thumbnail() ? '' : 'featured-no-image'; ?>
                              <div class="below-entry-meta <?php echo $no_featured_image_extra_class; ?>">
                                 <?php
                                    $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
                                    $time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
                                       esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
                                       esc_html( get_the_date() )
                                    );
                                    printf( __( '<span class="posted-on"><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> %3$s</a></span>', 'colornews' ),
                                       esc_url( get_permalink() ),
                                       esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
                                       $time_string
                                    );
                                 ?>

                                 <span class="byline"><span class="author vcard"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><a class="url fn n" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_author(); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_author() ); ?></a></span></span>
                                 <span class="comments"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i><?php comments_popup_link( '0', '1', '%' );?></span> <br>


                              </div> 

                              <div class="category-content" style="    margin-top: 17px;
    margin-left: -3px;">
            `               
                                 <?php

                                       if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                          $image = '';

                                          $image .= '<figure>';

                                             $image .= colornews_colored_category_return(0);
                                          $image .= '</figure>';
                                          echo $image;
                                       }
                                       ?>


                              </div> 

                              <div class="entry-content">
                                 <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                              </div>
                              <div class="entry-btn">
                                 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('বিস্তারিত <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>', 'colornews'); ?></a>
                              </div>

                           </div>
                        </div></div></div>

                  <?php

                  endwhile;


                      $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages = $get_featured_posts->max_num_pages;
                the_posts_pagination( array(
                   'mid_size' => 2,
                   'prev_text' => __( '<-', 'green' ),
                   'next_text' => __( '->', 'green' ),
                   'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Posts navigation' )
                ) ); 




                  // Reset Post Data
                  wp_reset_query();
                  ?>
                  <?php 






                ?>


               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <?php echo $after_widget;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Posts in Page — WordPress Plugins.
Here is the plugin link 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-in-page/

you can also see how its work
https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-in-page/installation/